# Facebook/Instagram Ads API: "The page-id and/or post-id didn't resolve to a valid story."

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to create an Ad on Instagram via the Facebook Ads API. Our system currently works fine with creating Ads to be published on Facebook, however when I try to create an Ad for Instagram I get the following error:

```
Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  POST
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_115305119273030/ads
  Params:  {'name': 'Ad Name', 'adset_id': '120330000035581316', 'creative': '{"object_story_spec":{"instagram_actor_id":"2318910634825810","link_data":{"caption":"www.puxaforte.com","description":"Description Text","link":"http://www.puxaforte.com/index2.html","message":"Message Text","name":"Headline Text","picture":"https://storage.googleapis.com/advio-middleware-local-develop/5fc51781-dd91-4a0d-ac7a-0151dee97b92.jpg"},"page_id":"422303898241282"}}', 'status': 'PAUSED'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1487531,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Cannot load publish info",
        "error_user_msg": "The page-id and/or post-id didn't resolve to a valid story.",
        "fbtrace_id": "CJpZSFaGMSP"
      }
    }
```

I have updated my code on the Facebook only version to include the `instagram_actor_id` and the `page_id` is the ID of the Facebook Page affiliated to the Instagram account.

I don't understand what it means by "resolve to a valid story" and a long time spent looking at the docs and googling online has yielded no results! Has anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey did you ever figure out this out?

Comment: Met this problem while using Ad Manager. Resolved by connecting/selecting a Facebook Page